# How I can fix this on UnityDecoration?

Tags: themes

Do you see below? There's a little space after the header bar at the left, how I can fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to open `[path to your theme]/gtk-3.0/apps/unity.css`, and replace
`-UnityDecoration-extents: 28px 0 0 0;` for `-UnityDecoration-extents: 28px 1px 1px 1px;`.

and add:

`border: 1px solid <your border color>;`

to `UnityDecoration.left, UnityDecoration.right {`